# crc 8 maxim jscript или VBScript

Tags: vbscript, crc, jscript

День добрый.
Требуется код для алгоритма контрольной суммы "crc 8 maxim" - передавать буду строку.
Применятся код будет в 1с.
Имеется возможно использовать код на языках 1с, jscript и VBScript.
Помогите пожалуйста с алгоритмом(нужна функция на перечисленных языках).

Имеется алгоритм для crc 8:

```
 function CRC8(strN)
{
strHex = new String(""0123456789ABCDEF"");
result = 0;
fctr = 16;
for (i=0; i<strN.length; i++)
    {
        if (strN.charAt(i) == '') continue;
        v = strHex.indexOf(strN.charAt(i));
        if (v < 0)
            {
            result = -1;
            break;
            }
        result += v * fctr;
        if (fctr == 16) fctr = 1; else fctr = 16;
    }
        // Calculate 2's complement
        result = (~(result & 0xff) + 1) & 0xFF;
        // Convert result to string
        //strResult = new String(result.toString());
        strResult = strHex.charAt(Math.floor(result/16)) + strHex.charAt(result%16);
        var a = strResult;
        return(a);
}
```

Comment: Абсолютно ничего не понятно. Выглядит как бессмысленный набор слов.

Comment: Поправил описание

Comment: Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос. Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности при решении задачи. Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу.

Comment: https://github.com/mslosarek/crc-multi/blob/master/src/crc.js#L13 параметры модели в models.json

Comment: Спасибо за ссылку. а сразу вариант как в теме можно? я с jscript от слова некак.